# what is the use of method final Cursor managedQuery (Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder)

Tags: android

Can someone please explain me what exactly is the use of

```
 final Cursor managedQuery (Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder)
```

method. Although I know its deprecated.

android developer's definition is beyond understanding. I want to understand in simple language

Comment: Googleing doesn't help in any ways?

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the Documentation:

> Wrapper around query(android.net.Uri, String[], String, String[], String) that gives the resulting Cursor to call startManagingCursor(Cursor) so that the activity will manage its lifecycle for you. If you are targeting HONEYCOMB or later, consider instead using LoaderManager instead, available via getLoaderManager().

It´s an activity lifeclicle managed query.

You can check it here [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#managedQuery(android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String)).